# Stackdriverのアラートの発生でインスタンスを実行できるようにしたい

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud

StackDriverのAWSモニタリング機能に、"Automation"という
"システムのステータスが一定の閾値を超えた際に、あらかじめ
ユーザが設定していた対応方法を自動実行する機能"が加わるという
2013年末月のニュースをたまたま拝見しました。

現在のGCPのStackdriverで
Automationと同じように、設定した閾値を超えれば対応のインスタンスを
落とすなどすることは不可能でしょうか。
希望ではアラートが発生すれば、設定していた対応を自動的に実行できるようにしたいです。

StackDriverのAutomation機能はGCPにはないのでしょうか。
ないのであれば、Cloud Functionsなどを使用して上記と同じような動作はできませんでしょうか。
どなたかお分かりの方いらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 僕が知る限りは、しきい値を超えた場合はアラートを行うという機能しかないですね。アラートはWebHockで投げれるので、アラートを受け取ったアプリケーションが指定動作を行うことは可能です。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。調べたところWebhookでいけそうですね。GCPで作成しているのでできればCloud Functions等で対応できたらうれしいのですが、難しいでしょうか。

Comment: コメントをいただいて質問を多少修正しました

Comment: WebhockをApp EngineやCloud Function, Compute Engineなど、なんらかのWebApplicationで受け取ってしまえば、あとは好きにプログラミングすれば、だいたいなんでもやることができます。